# Issue with Javascript - JQuery and selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

i have the following code:

```
 <div id="imgThumb">
        <img id="t1" src="images/cards/1.png" style="display:none; "/><img id="t13" src="images/cards/13.png" style="display:none; "/>img id="t15" src="images/cards/15.png" style="display:none; "/><img id="t16" src="images/cards/16.png" style="display:none; "/>            
    </div>
    <div id="cardHolder" class="rounded-border">
        <div class="title"></div>
        <div id="cardsInvestigated"><h1>In hand</h1>
            <div value="t1" class="impar tecnologia unselected investigated">Adrenalina GreenDragonFly</div><div value="t15" class="impar tecnologia unselected investigated">Diplomatico Wissenland</div>            </div>
        <div id="cardsNotInvestigated"><h1>Not investigated</h1>
            <div value="t13" class="par tecnologia unselected notinvestigated">Centinela Saisei</div><div value="t16" class="par tecnologia unselected notinvestigated">Emboscada Arthuria</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Then i have the following javascript:

```
    $('.investigated.active').click(function(){
    //jugar tarjeta
    alert ('jugar');
})

$('.notinvestigated.active').click(function(){
    //investigar tarjeta
    alert ('investigar');
})


$(".unselected").click(function (){
    alert('click on unselected')
    $('#'+$('.active').attr('value')).toggle();
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('unselected');
    //$(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('active');
    $('#message div:last-child').remove();
    $('#message').append('<div id="message1">Has seleccionado la tarjeta '+$(this).text()+'</div>');
    $('#'+$(this).attr('value')).toggle();

})
```

Now, when i click on the div it works perfectly and changes the class (removes unselected and add active) however when i click on it again it triggers the unselected function instead of the active function. Can anyone tell me what's going on?

**Answer**:
As suggested by Felix the following code works:

```
    $('#cardHolder').on('click','.investigated.active',(function(){
    alert ('jugar');
}))

$('#cardHolder').on('click','.notinvestigated.active',(function(){
    //investigar tarjeta
    alert ('investigar');
}))


$("#cardHolder").on("click",'.unselected',(function(){
    alert('click on unselected')
    $('#'+$('.active').attr('value')).toggle();
    $('.active').removeClass('active').addClass('unselected');
    //$(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).removeClass('unselected').addClass('active');
    $('#message div:last-child').remove();
    $('#message').append('<div id="message1">Has seleccionado la tarjeta '+$(this).text()+'</div>');
    $('#'+$(this).attr('value')).toggle();

}))
```

Comment: let me read it and see if it helps me out. live() worked like a charm but using on() is giving me the same result as using click

Comment: Well, you have to use `.on` in the corrected way ;) `.live` is deprecated and was replaced by `.on`. If you read the jQuery documentation, you will know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your jquery runs it will bind the actions to the html tags.  Changing their class will not make them trigger a different event because the click callback has already been bound.
What you're looking for is the "on" method for binding events.

Live doesn't bind events to the tags themselves, but to the document, and whenever the document is clicked, it will look to see if what was clicked matches the selector.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Basically, instead of doing this

```
$('.investigated.active').click(function(){
```

You'll do this

```
$('.investigated.active').on("click",function(){
```

Comment: Don't use `$.live` (deprecated since 1.7) - use `$.on` in its place.

Comment: Do **NOT** use `live()` use `on()`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I had not seen the deprecation of the live() method.  You learn something new everyday.  I'll edit my response for this.

Comment: using on gives me the same result as using click

Comment: He's right.  Using live() works as expected, using on() works as like bind()  http://jsfiddle.net/thinkingsites/jHMV4/4/  EH_Warch, I might keep live for now, until we figure out why on is not working.

Comment: Hey thanks. Well looking into the answer suggested by FelixKling, i got it working, for what i could understand i have to bind the event to a parent and then have to specify on() to look for changes on a sibling with a 'XXXX' selector. Im going to post the javscript that solves the problem.

Comment: I see.  Like I'd mentioned earlier, I'm new to the on functionality for dynamic binding, so that's good to know.